# accessing app service from domain object

Tags: domain-driven-design

Can a domain entity can call or app service layer, through service layer interface ? Please tell me way also ?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

Domain entities should not know about the application service layer.  The application service layer's job is to coordinate actions between domain objects, across bounded contexts if necessary.

In my experience, this is a pretty strict rule so if you feel you need to break it you've probably got a design problem further up the chain.